# Cube rotation with particles inside

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

Imagine I've got a cube in space with particles inside, what I need to do is rotate the cube in a way that each time one of the faces points up (so I guess I need to do 6 rotations of 90 degrees each), obviously every time I rotate the cube the particles inside need to be rotated as well so this would be my procedure:

1. Translate to the origin every cube vertex and particle position applying the proper scaling matrix
2. Rotate around the x or y or z axis (every rotation is unique so i change the current cube face facing up)
3. Rotate all the particles for the same quantity(so usually 90 degrees)
4. Translate back everything
5. Start again for the next face

Does this make sense?

How can I align the cube to the x/y/z axis if the object I get is not align? (so this should be my first rotation  I guess)

Comment: regarding the 1st part (1-5), it is not clear to me what's you're asking. What you wrote makes sense - what's the difficulty? Regarding the last question, this is very obscure. Is the cube populated densely and evenly, but rotated randomly in space? In such a case, you're question makes sense.

Comment: Hi Ophir, thank you for your replay, I'ts  not difficult but I wanted to ask to be sure that what I am doing it's correct.